# c# - Split large file into multiple files

Tags: c#, sql

I looked around online, and I could find some things but not really what I want.

I have a SQL file that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `cola`(`url`, `page`, `c_id`) VALUES
(`{0}`, `{1}`, 0),
(`{0}`, `{1}`, 0),
(`{0}`, `{1}`, 0), ... 300 times
(`{0}`, `{1}`, 0);
INSERT INTO...
```

{0} and {1} are the values.
I can only upload a max of 50MiB in my phpMyAdmin, so I need to split this file.
I found things online, but they splitted the file exactly at 50MiB, without letting the line end.

So what I want is:
Split the file into 48 - 49MiB files, and let the last line be `(`{0}`,`{1}`, 0);` and the next file starting with

```
INSERT INTO `cola`(`url`, `page`, `c_id`) VALUES
```

What I have now:

```
StreamReader GET = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\sql.sql");

        string line;
        int fileId = 0;
        int lineId = 0;
        long fileLenght = 0;

        while ((line = GET.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lineId++;

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\ye\" + fileId.ToString() + ".sql")) sw.WriteLine(line);

            if (lineId == 50000)
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\ye\" + fileId.ToString() + ".sql");
                fileLenght = f.Length;
                Console.Title = fileLenght.ToString();
                lineId = 0;
            }

            if (fileLenght > 50000000 && line.EndsWith(");"))
            {
                fileLenght = 0;
                fileId++;
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\ye\" + fileId.ToString() + ".sql")) fs.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Created: " + fileId.ToString());
            }

        }

        GET.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Core - SQL is done.");
```

This works, but it is very slow. Any idea's to make it faster?

The file I am splitting is 4GB.

Comment: Why not split your file on INSERT statements. Is this a one-off piece?

Comment: @Yahya If I split it on each INSERT statement, I will get too much files. I want files of about 48/49 MiB.

Comment: This is not the first time you have just given C#

Comment: This has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: @MatthewWhited It does, I want to make a program that does this in c#

Comment: Then show us the C# you have so far.  SO is not a programming service

Comment: @MatthewWhited I have nothing, I looked up some things but they where not what I want. I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I edited my question

Comment: If you are really worried about performance only open and close each file once.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I thought about that, but how can I find out the file size if I do not auto update it?

Comment: keep a local counter

Comment: And you STILL have not listed the framework.  Yes we can infer .NET from what you finally posted.

Comment: @MatthewWhited OP is very clear that a byte spit will break up the statements./

Comment: No one said to split it based on a byte count.  If you look at my answer it will read in the file in blocks and split on `INSERT INTO`.  If there are more patterns to split on you can add those as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar project years ago. The way I handled it was bringing in chunks that were X size (49MB in your case), then scanning backwards (use String.LastIndexOf) for the beginning of the last key (in your case that would be "Insert Into". Everything to the left of the String.LastIndexOf result is saved in a file then the remainder of that string is prepended to the next X-Y (49MB - size of remainder string) bytes that I loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code coming:

```
open main file
n=1
open chunk[n]
while not !eof main file
{
  read line from main file
  if chunk stream . position+size of line < chunksize 
    write line to chunk
  else
  {
    close chunk
    n+1
    open new chunk
    write line to new chunk
  }
}
close chunk
close main file
```

Now you have your file in whole lines, in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  You may need to play around if you have more than just insert statements in the script.

```
var filename = "outfile.sql";
var spliton = "INSERT INTO";
var expectedEnd = ";";

var outcount = 0;
var filecounter = 0;
var outfileformatter = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) + "_{0}" +
                        Path.GetExtension(filename);

string outfile = null;
StreamWriter writer = null;
var blocksize = 32 * 1024;
var block = new char[blocksize];
// by using StreamReader you won't have to load the entire file into memory
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        // read in sections of the file at a time since you can't hold the entire thing in memory.
        var outsize = reader.ReadBlock(block, 0, blocksize);
        var content = new string(block, 0, outsize);

        // split the data by your seperator.
        var chunks = content.Split(new[] { spliton }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .Select(c => spliton + c);

        // loop over the chunks of data 
        foreach (var chunk in chunks)
        {
                //once the threshold is tripped close the writer and open the next
                if (outcount > 48 * 1024 * 1024 || outfile == null) //48MB - 
                {
                    if (expectedEnd != null && !chunk.TrimEnd().TrimEnd('\n', '\r').EndsWith(expectedEnd))
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("+++extend");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filecounter++;
                        outcount = 0;
                        if (writer != null)
                            writer.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine(outfile);
                        outfile = string.Format(outfileformatter, filecounter);
                        writer = new StreamWriter(outfile);
                    }
                }
            //output the data
            writer.Write(chunk);
            //record how much data you wrote to the file.
            outcount += Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chunk).Length;
            //if the file is only ascii you could cheat and just say 'chunk.Length'.
        }

    }
}
if (writer != null)
    writer.Close();
```

...as written this doesn't parse SQL.  If you have more than just insert statements or for some crazy reason an insert statement longer than 48MB you may have issues with this spliting code.  But you could always make sure the last statement being written to the file ends in a Semicolon `;` or modify the parsing/splitting logic to meet your needs.